# Container services in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

Recently, I started to study about containers and I am challenged to start using it in the production environment.
I use AWS as a cloud platform and would like to hear from you on this subject.
In your experiments and labs, what is the best way, in your opinion, of using containers in Amazon Web Services?

Comment: I flagged your question as primarily opinion based, it could also be considered too broad. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Containers on ECS are very familiar to how you would normally run containers on a server. [ECS reference architecture](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation)
2. EKS which is effectively managed Kubernetes (AWS managed the master nodes) has the advantage of scheduler which orchestrates container deployment as well as functionality to manage the containers. (I believe this is the future of running container workloads). It has the negative of being a slightly steep learning curve.
3. Then I think it would also be important to include AWS Lambda which are serverless functions which effectively are short lived containers 0-15 mins. This to me is very quick to stand up a POC and is very easy to port into containers at a later stage. However they are bad if you are planning on doing a lot of IO related tasks as you pay for the time that they are idle due to the blocking nature of IO.

That being said it really depends on your use case and what your workload is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning for aws then

Amazon web services provide 2 container service : ECS & EKS

**ECS**

- ECS managed service by amazon it self.
- It is also knows as farget
- You donot have to worry about node and relaying resources (EC2
  etc)amazon manage. You have to simply provide container details
- Easy to setup compare to EKS. not much initialising timing
- Two configuration in ECS farget & ECS farget + EC2

**EKS**

- EKS is knows as Elastic Kubernetes service
- you have to setup node (how much and other configuration)
- you can edit node or resources
- take little time to setup

Plus point of using aws for container is that aws manage auto scaling, horizontal pod scaling and vertical pod scaling

If you have limited traffic and small application Go for digital ocean it is so cheap compare to aws

but remember digital ocean not support horizontal & vertical auto scaling

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides two type of managed container orchestration services

1. **AWS ECS - Elastic Container Service**
2. **AWS EKS - Elastic Kubernetes Service**

If you are just getting started with the container world, choose ECS. It is easy to get started and integrates well into the AWS ecosystem.

Once you are familiar, try Kubernetes. Kubernetes does have a steep learning curve but is well worth it. It's a graduated CNCF project and is the future of container orchestration.